# How do I convert a deliminated file in base - R into separate columns without creating a list?

Tags: r, string, parsing

I currently do this using the following code:

```
write(unlist(fieldList),"c:/temp/test.txt")
temp1<-cbind(fieldList,read.delim("c:/temp/test.txt",sep=" ",header=FALSE))
```

but this is slow because it obliges the app to write data to temp file on disk.

I have tried `strsplit` function and "qdap" library but they both create lists. I need to be able to manipulate the columns separately

```
NewColumn <- substr(temp1[,5],1,1)
```

Comment: What does `fieldList` look like? Can you add a sample of it to the question by using `dput(head(fieldList))` or similar?

Comment: @Englshbob What is fieldList? What does your file look like?  Have you tried `read.csv` with the `sep` argument set to whatever your delimiter is (from your question it looks like `' '`)?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample data and code you're using?  This is expected when you post and leads to fast, accurate responses.